# Angular Material Switch A Color When Switching Theme

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have implemented Angular Material Dark and Light theme. With this I can change the colors based on the theme using for example `mat-color($primary)`. This works fine but now I need to use a different color altogether. So instead of the primary color with hue 200 in light theme: `mat-color($primary, 200)`, I want to be able to use primary color with an 800 hue in dark theme `mat-color($primary, 800)`.

**data-table-theme.scss**

```
@mixin data-table-color($color-config) {
  $primary: map-get($color-config, primary);

  .data-table {
    background-color: mat-color($primary, 200);
  }

}
```

**data-table.html**

```
<div class="page-container mat-app-background"
     [ngClass]="(isDarkTheme$ | async) ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-default'">

  <div class="data-table"></div>

</div>
```

I tried adding `theme-dark` selector in custom component style but that didn't work.

```
@mixin data-table-color($color-config) {
  $primary: map-get($color-config, primary);

  .theme-default .data-table {
    background-color: mat-color($primary, 200);
  }

  .theme-dark .data-table {
    background-color: mat-color($primary, 800);
  }

}
```

I look forward to hearing your solutions.

**Edit**

The solution I tried doesn't work because angular material generates the css at compile time. So it will then create:

```
.theme-default .data-table {
  background-color: #c5cae9;
}

.theme-dark .data-table {
  background-color: #1a237e;
}

.theme-dark .theme-dark .data-table {
  background-color: #ff6f00;
}

.theme-dark .theme-default .data-table {
  background-color: #ffecb3;
}
```

This causes it to change hue but the color used is the light primary color.

I have uploaded a test project to Stackblitz, which unfortunately doesn't compile some of the angular material dependencies. But if you run it locally you will see what I mean.

https://stackblitz.com/github/kdrpt/angular-test-project

Answer (score 2):

Looking in your stackblitz example, it seems you forgot to import your `app.theme.scss` in the root `styles.scss`.

```
@import 'theme/app-theme.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the include statement for you mixin in your scss file?

```
@include data-table-color($color-config);
```

Just add the above statement in your scss file (where you have defined your @mixin data-table-color) and pass the *$color-config* that you have created. It is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Which part of the code are you referring to when you say 'it's working fine for me'. Because the first 2 snippets do work, as stated in the question. But what they do is simply flip the color from the light primary (200) to dark primary (200). What I'm trying to do is when dark mode is active use for example primary (800) or even the secondary color rather than the primary.

Comment: Along with the first two snippets, the third snippet that you tried is correct and working for me. Instead of changing to dark primary (200), it is changing to primary(800) when dark mode is selected as coded in your third snippet. Did you check if your [ngClass] is working as expected?

Comment: I've editted my question with some more info regarding your feedback.